# Is './' a valid path to submit a form to the same page for processing with PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms

I am submitting an HTML form to the same page to handle with PHP and figured out that I can use `action="./"`, which works fine for me so far (in a test environment).

I am a little unsure though because all the examples I find recommend using either
`action=""`
or
`action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>"`

I don't want to use `action=""` because the [HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#form-submission-attributes) specifically states

> The action and formaction content attributes, if specified, must have a value that is a valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces.

Is there any reason not to use `action="./"`? It seems better (more readable, less PHP) to me but it's confusing me that all the examples I find recommend the PHP approach.

Comment: You can completely omit the `action` attribute because the default behaviour is to submit to self.

Comment: `./` does not mean the same page. It means the same folder. Example: `/foo/form.php` would then submit to `/foo` (which in a default setting would mean `/foo/index.php`) and not to `/foo/form.php`. With SEO friendly URL's, `/foo/bar` would submit to `/foo` and `/foo/bar/` (with trailing slash) would submit to `/foo/bar/`.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense now. Is there any reason to ever even use `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>"` then?

Comment: @Isak Maybe it was making sense when action was required attr for forms, but since HTML5 its not required and if action is specified needs to be valid non-empty URL, as you noted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `./` works in a lot of cases but can lead to unwanted behaviour if not understood correctly. It's also unnecessary as default behaviour of forms without the `action` attribute is to submit the form to the same page.

Use `<form method="post">` to submit to the same page.

Don't use `<form action="" method="post">`. This will also submit to the same page but it's invalid according to the [HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#form-submission-attributes).